# How to find length of element in simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

i am using `simple_html_dom` for for render html in php. In one case i have to check the availability of one particular division. i used following code but but when ever i am using `if(isset($GroupHtmlDom->find('#groupFooter')))` condition in my code it crashing my wamp server(see the picture), i dont know y.. following is the exact code i'm using.

```
 foreach($htmlDom->find('#divGroupSection') as $div{
    $GroupHtmlDom = new simple_html_dom();
    $GroupHtmlDom = str_get_html($div);
    if(isset($GroupHtmlDom->find('#groupFooter')))
        $groupFooter = $GroupHtmlDom->find('#groupFooter')[0]->innertext;
    else
        $groupFooter = '';
    }
```

how to use `jquery length` here? `$GroupHtmlDom->find('#groupFooter').length` is it correct? or instead of `isset()` is there any other way?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php function [strlen](http://php.net/strlen)

i.e.:

```
if(isset($GroupHtmlDom->find('#groupFooter'))){
  $groupFooter = $GroupHtmlDom->find('#groupFooter')[0]->innertext; 
   echo strlen($groupFooter);
}else{
  $groupFooter = ''; 
}
```

---

> ## strlen
>
> Returns the length of the given string.

Answer (score 1):

You would think so, but instead you want count:

```
echo count($GroupHtmlDom->find('#groupFooter'));
```